# How to Run Laravel php 7.2 with php 5.5

Tags: php, laravel-5

I was wandering if there is anyway that I can run My project that is php 7.2 on php 5.5 .Since I'm using 7.2.

Comment: A much quicker and wiser idea would be to upgrade to a supported version of PHP

Comment: You use docker container

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in [PHP Roadmap](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php), Php 5.5 is deprecated since 2016, this version is no more maintained and potentially subject to security vulnerabilities. So, it is dangerous to deploy a website on a so old PHP version.

You should upgrade your php version on your site and then deploy Laravel on it. (And it will be easier!)